# Postman SOAP call does not work any way I change it

Tags: soap, postman

I am trying to test connection to Riksbank to get exchange rates for EUR-SEK currency. Through Altova Mapforce I am able to connect, but once I try testing with postman I cannot seem to get it working.

Riksbank uses SOAP method. [Documentation is here](https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/docs/api/index.htm)
[Method I use is here](https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/docs/api/call/getInterestAndExchangeRates.htm)

When I use the URL with an OPTIONS method I get 200 code and headers returned. But no result body:
[image: OPTIONS result]

I changed the Content-Type heather and tried with body and without body:
[image: Headers]
[image: Body]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your example working by changing two things;

- Change your method to `POST`
- Change your `Content-Type` to `application/soap+xml;charset=utf8;action=urn:getInterestAndExchangeRates`as suggested in the documentary of the API

I got this response with above 2 changes:
[image: response]

Comment: Thank you very much! I would have never guessed that I should put all headers together under Content-Type. I was trying to split them. It works now.